# How to replace high bit for each character in a text file using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hex

I need to convert source files from an old CAN-8 system to/from standard ASCII.

The CAN-8 files have each byte with the high bit on (0x80).

So I need to do something like:

```
f=File.new
can8=f.read
```

... do something with variable `can8`

When I display the `can8` variable it looks like `"\xC1\xC2\xC3"`,  I need to convert that to `"ABC"` (`"\x41\x42\x43"`)

Mike

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it:

```
original_string = "\xC1\xC2\xC3"
converted_string = original_string.bytes.collect { |b| (b & 0x7f).chr }.join
```

You didn't specify a Ruby version, so I will assume you are using 1.9 or later.

Comment: I assume you meant original_string.bytes.collect :)

Answer (score 0):

The following little script seems to do the job:

```
File.open("/etc/passwd").each_byte { |char|
    print (char & 0x7F).chr()
}
```

The `char & 0x7F` turns off the high-bit, and `chr()` turns the number back into a character.

Comment: Thanks guys ... 

Samold, I tried to "useful" click yours, but it says something about my reputation not being high enough

Comment: You need [15 or more reputation points](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) to vote up answers. I'm sure you'll get those points soon enough, at which point the site gets a _lot_ more fun.